# Unable to locate package libgles1-mesa-dev

Tags: apt, 17.04

In zesty, `apt` can find `libgles2-mesa-dev`, but for some reason is unable to find `libgles1-mesa-dev`.

How to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrei, The package `libgles1-mesa-dev` is available for all architecture until `yakkety`. In `zesty`, (strangely though) its available only for `powerpc`.

Whereas `libgles2-mesa-dev` is available for all architectures. ([Reference](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgles1-mesa-dev))

Hope this helps!
-- Mike